# Using two databases interchangeably with identical structures but different naming conventions

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

At some point in time, we changed the naming schema we use for our database.  Every single table name and column name in the database was renamed, but the structure remained identical.

I need to be able to read from both current and legacy tables in my program.  Up to now, we simply had a set of large mapping arrays we would use to convert the results on the fly.  We've discovered that accessing this array thousands of times in our PHP code to convert every column name in every row of every result is significantly hurting our performance.

What's the best way to solve this?  Can it be done from within SQL Server?

Comment: If your mapping table is a hashtable then the performance impact would be negligible. How are you performing your lookup? What performance stats do you have that show it's a performance hit?

Comment: @Dai An actual single lookup is pretty negligible - only 0.082 ms per lookup.  The problem is we are pulling in whole tables of data at certain times, meaning that for one operation this lookup gets hit like 60,000 times.  The total performance hit is almost 5 seconds.  Without the lookup, it's almost instantaneous, and this is in a section of the program where 5 seconds is unacceptable to the user.

Comment: Do the lookup before doing the query and let the SQL server give it to you with the correct name. Say you have a column named 'my_column' and you want it to be 'myColumn', then you can just do `SELECT my_column AS myColumn, ... FROM ...`

Comment: @JustinWarkentin This was the approach I was thinking of and may be the best.  We have a home built data access layer that would need to be rewritten somewhat if we use this methodology.  If there is no other way, this will probably be the approach we take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two easiest options are:

- Create a view for every renamed table.  The old table name is the new name for your view.  The old columns map to the new columns.  No application code changes needed.
- Or, if you have a layer of code to do the mappings you're presumably using an ORM or some other DB abstraction layer.  If possible, do your mapping here before the query by adding column alias names, or renaming result set object / array fields.

Comment: Views are the perfect solution for this.  Thank you.